# How to find individual rank from a table which consists of gold silver and bronze medal

Tags: mysql

How do I find the individual rank from the below table, for same points the rank should also be the same , just like the Olympic medal table.

Table as below:

```
          Gold Slvr B   Total
India      44   0   0   0
Australia   7   0   0   0
Pakistan    5   0   1   6
Zimbabwe    2   2   2   5
Afghanistan 2   0   0   0
NewZealand  1   1   0   2
England     1   1   0   2
```

Comment: Could you be more specific, what result do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need a query to find the Rank of single country, for eg. A query to find the rank of Zimbabwe which is 3rd rank, and the the rank of newZealand and England would result a 6th rank, because they have equal number of gold , silver and bronze. So the query should sort the rank based on maximum number of gold, then max silver then max bronze and max total.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you want something like this:

```
ORDER BY MAX(Gold) DESC, MAX(Slvr) DESC, MAX(B) DESC
```

For including a rank with each row, see [Rank function in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer as below :-

select rank,email,tgolds,tsilver,tbronze from (SELECT email, tgolds, tsilver, tbronze , @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM results p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY  tgolds desc ,tsilver desc,tbronze desc,tmedal desc, date asc ) as k where k.email = '$_SESSION[email]'";